# Pivot Table in Pandas with two column(Index and Value)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a CSV file with `obj` and `VS` column.
I need to sum `VS` values for each `obj` and have output like below

**Input:**

```
+-----+------+
| obj |  VS  |
+-----+------+
| B   | 2048 |
| A   | 1024 |
| B   |   10 |
| A   | 1024 |
| B   | 1025 |
| A   | 1026 |
| B   | 1027 |
+-----+------+
```

**Output:**

```
+---+------+
| A | 3074 |
+---+------+
| B | 4110 |
+---+------+
```

I have tried below code,As I have just two column to apply I added `value` column with unique value to have pivot(pivot table need Index,Column and Value).Then `Value` column is just to help. However out put is sum thing weird!!!

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

filename='1test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype='str')
df["value"]=1
pd.pivot_table(df, values="VS", index="obj", columns="value", aggfunc=np.sum)
```

**output of my code**:

```
+-------+----------------+
| value |       1        |
+-------+----------------+
| obj   |                |
| A     |   102410241026 |
| B     | 20481010251027 |
+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: df.VS=pd.to_numeric(df.VS), then do your pivot

Comment: Because the dtype = 'str' the aggregate func is adding the strings for each row  instead of adding the numerical value.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider that as you read from CSV, values are string, you need to convert them to int by `df['VS']=pd.to_numeric(df['VS'])`
`print(df.dtypes)` show the type of column in df

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

filename='1test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, dtype='str')
df["value"]=1
print(df.dtypes)
df['VS']=pd.to_numeric(df['VS'])
print(df.dtypes)
pd.pivot_table(df, values="VS", index="obj", columns="value", aggfunc=np.sum)
```